# JavaFx copy file to system clipboard and paste in os

Tags: javafx, operating-system, copy, clipboard, paste

I have following problem: I copy file or folder to system clipboard. It realy simple, here the code:

```
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import java.nio.file.Path;

@Override
public void copyHandler(Path path) {
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putFiles(singletonList(path.toFile()));

    Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContent(content);
}
```

But after success copy, I go to my OS(Ubuntu 16.04) filesystem explorer, click right mouse and try to paste, but paste menu is disabled. What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Try this : `content.putFiles(java.util.Collections.singletonList(new File("path to file")));`

Answer (score 2):

Here the specific solution for Ubuntu Nautilus File-Manager:

```
public static final DataFormat GNOME_FILES = new DataFormat("x-special/gnome-copied-files");

if (platform == Platform.Linux64 || platform == Platform.Linux32) {

        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("copy\n");

        paths.forEach(builder, (path, b) ->
                b.append(path.toUri().toASCIIString()).append('\n'));

        builder.delete(builder.length() - 1, builder.length());

        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(builder.length());

        for (int i = 0, length = builder.length(); i < length; i++) {
            buffer.put((byte) builder.charAt(i));
        }

        buffer.flip();

        content.put(GNOME_FILES, buffer);
    }
```